# Angular 4 - Close iframe after redirect

Tags: angular, iframe

I have an angular 4 app.
I'm using a third party payment system (named Tranzila). Tranzila provide a easy integration using an iframe. Within the iframe, the user is performing the payment in Tranzila domain, which saving me the time to build the form and handle the credit card numbers.
Tranzila provide me the ability to configure the success and error post requests after the user submit the request.
My problem is that I want to close the iframe after a successfull payment request, and redirect the user to a page in my site (not inside the iframe). 
I'm trying to find the best way to close the iframe after the request. Since the payment page can not be customized with javascript, I can't manipulate their page to close the iframe after a successfull request.

I thought about 2 options:
1.Use Tranzila default "Payment success" page and trying to listen to iframe src change from my site.
2. Customize their page to navigate to a "Payment Success" page in my domain.
Add a route to a page in my domain that will call a function declared in parent, which will close the iframe and navigate to a success route.

For now, 
I implement app-payment-order as follow:

```js
 import { Credentials } from '../_models/credentials.model';

import { CredentialsStorageService } from '../_services/credentials-storage.service';
import { ItemOverview } from '../_models/item-overview.interface';
import { OrderItemsOverview } from '../_models/order-overview.interface';
import { OrderDto } from '../_models/order-dto.model';
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-order-payment',
  templateUrl: './order-payment.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./order-payment.component.scss']
})
export class OrderPaymentComponent {
  @Input('order')
  public order:OrderDto;

  constructor(private readonly credentials: CredentialsStorageService) {
  //Option 2 - Add function to window. this function will be called from the iframe after loading a special page from my domain which will call parent.paymentSuccess
    window.paymentSuccess = () => {
    //Redirect to success page
     }
  }


  get iframeSrc(): string {
    let userCredentials: Credentials = this.credentials.get();
    return "https://myTranzilaMockUrl.com/iframe.php?sum={0}&currency=1&cred_type=1&orderId={1}&email={2}"
      .format(this.order.price.toString(), this.order.id, userCredentials && userCredentials.email);
  }
  
  //Option 1 - try to listen to iframe source change
  onIframeSrcChange() {
      //if iframe source changed to success page than redirect
  }
  
  
  
  
}
```

```html
<div class="order-payment-container" *ngIf="order != null">
 <!-- <iframe [src]="iframeSrc | safe" scrolling="no" class="app-tranzila-iframe" ></iframe>-->
</div>
```

Sorry about the mess, I hope I succeeded to describe the issue well.

Answer (score 1):

You should always use their "success" or "failure" callback to handle the end of the transaction, it's there for a reason.

callback and there do whatever you need to on the parent page. 
you should also consider using this page to tell your server the new status of the transaction.